# Wrapping TimerOutputs macros

Tags: macros, julia

I've got a situation where it would be handy to have a variable, `to`, which can either be a `TimerOutput` or `nothing`. I'm interested in providing a macro that takes the same arguments as `@timeit` from TimerOutputs (e.g. `@timeit to "time spent" s = foo()`). Because `to` is potentially set to `nothing`, I can't simply disable a TimerObject.

If `to` is set, my preference would be to pass the arguments along to `@timeit`, but could live with calling `timer_expr(__module__, false, args...)`.

If `to` is not set, I'd want to just return the remaining arguments (something like `args[3:end]`, maybe) as an expression.

I've been fussing with this for a day or so, and can handle each of the cases in isolation. For the case where I'm not involving TimerOutput, this seems to work:

```
macro no_timer(args...)
    args[3:end][1]
end
```

And for the case where I *am* using TimerOutput, I can do this:

```
macro with_timer(args...)
    timer_expr(__module__, false, args...)
end
```

Not surprising, as that's just what `@timeit` does.

I haven't figured out how to handle both cases in one macro. I've gotten the closest by wrapping everything in a ternary operator - i.e.  `return :(isnothing($(args[1])) ? <expression stuff> : <TimerOutput stuff>)`, but there is some level of abstraction mismatch that I haven't unsnarled.

Addendum: I've come to the conclusion that my original framing was an "X-Y" problem. I didn't actually need a new macro to solve my problem - hence my accepting the answer I did. That said, I am struck by the fact that both of the answers proffered stayed well away from defining a macro.

Comment: " can handle each of the cases in isolation" could you share the code you have so far for that?

Comment: @SundarR I'll edit the question to include the partial solutions. Can't do it right now, I'm afraid.

Comment: @SundarR More details now in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already this functionality in TimerOuputs.
Just use `disable_timer!` and `enable_timer!` methods.

```
julia> const to = TimerOutput();

julia> disable_timer!(to);

julia> @timeit to "sleep" sleep(0.02)

julia> to
 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                            Time                    Allocations
                   ───────────────────────   ────────────────────────
 Tot / % measured:      23.6s /   0.0%            464KiB /   0.0%

 Section   ncalls     time    %tot     avg     alloc    %tot      avg
 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

julia> enable_timer!(to);


julia> @timeit to "sleep" sleep(0.02)

julia> to
 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                            Time                    Allocations
                   ───────────────────────   ────────────────────────
 Tot / % measured:      37.3s /   0.1%            777KiB /   0.0%

 Section   ncalls     time    %tot     avg     alloc    %tot      avg
 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 sleep          1   22.6ms  100.0%  22.6ms      320B  100.0%     320B
 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: I'm not necessarily going to have a TimerOutput object available to disable.

Comment: you could define your own method `disable` that dispatches on object type and eg. does nothing when the object is `nothing`. Hard to tell without more details - so perhaps you need to extend your question.

Comment: Pretty sure that `@timeit` isn't going to be happy if there isn't a bona fide TimerOutput as its first argument.

Comment: Looking at `@macroexpand @timeit to "sleep" sleep(0.02)` any `struct` that has field `enabled` with value `false` false will do.

Comment: That's pretty neat - thanks for sharing it.

Comment: If you edit your answer to include the information about just needing a struct with an `enable` field, I'd be happy to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own more specific version of the `timer_expr` function that the macro calls, where the returned expression contains a check for `to` argument being `nothing`, then doing the appropriate thing.

```
import TimerOutputs: timer_expr

function timer_expr(m::Module, is_debug::Bool, to::Symbol, label::String, ex::Expr)
  unescaped(ex) = ex.head == :escape ? ex.args[1] : ex

  # this is from the original timer_expr functions, 
  #  to be used when `to` isn't nothing
  timer_ex = TimerOutputs.is_func_def(ex) ? 
                    unescaped(TimerOutputs.timer_expr_func(m, is_debug, to, ex, label)) : 
                    TimerOutputs._timer_expr(m, is_debug, to, label, ex)
  
  cond_ex = esc(:(if isnothing($to)
      $ex
    else
      placeholder  # dummy symbol, to be replaced
    end))

  # args[3] = "else" section, 
  #   the placeholder is args[2] within that
  unescaped(cond_ex).args[3].args[2] = timer_ex

  cond_ex
end
```